# is there a way to find out exactly how kubuntu sets up KDE so I can just duplicate that?

Tags: kde, arch-linux

I usually use kubuntu, but I had to install a custom kernel on my laptop and it's a lot easier with arch. The problem is that kde looks terrible in arch, especially the GTK applications. I know there are all sorts of tutorials of installing gnome icons, and various peicewise fixes, but is there a way to find out exactly how kubuntu sets up KDE so I can just duplicate that?

Comment: Obviously GTK are not part of KDE. You could look at what GTK theme Kubuntu uses, and what theme settings it uses for KDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kubuntu makes many modifications to various applications (e.g., Firefox, OpenOffice), so it is unlikely that there is an easy way to recreate the Kubuntu look on ArchLinux.

That being said, I moved from Kubuntu to ArchLinux and I now prefer the vanilla applications (e.g., OpenOffice looks much better).

One thing that helped a lot in synchronizing the look of gtk applications with KDE was to install qtcurve, a theme that works for both qt (KDE) and gtk (Gnome) apps.

```
pacman -S qtcurve-gtk2 qtcurve-kde4 gtk-chtheme
gtk-chtheme
# Change the theme for qtcurve
```

Answer (score 4):

On Arch you should consider installing **[KDEmod](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KDEmod)** ( from [The Chakra Project](http://chakra-project.org/) ) instead of KDE.

> Install a minimal KDE4 system:
>
> ```
> # pacman -S kdemod-minimal
> ```
>
> Alternatively, fetch a richer set of
>   applications:
>
> ```
> # pacman -S kdemod
> ```
>
> or opt for a fuller set:
>
> ```
> # pacman -S kdemod-complete
> ```

According to the **[kdemod wiki](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KDEmod)**, you will need to install this package :

```
pacman -S kdemod-extragear-gtk-qt-engine
```

to get a more uniform look for QT and GTK apps.

Also checkout this [article](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uniform_Look_for_QT_and_GTK_Applications).

Comment: I chose the other answer because I already had KDE installed and configured. So I didn't want to uninstall and reinstall from chakra. +1 though

Answer (score 1):

Sadly KDEMod Repositories is no longer active.

Use [this](http://chakra-project.org/) now.